# Progress Bar custom Design like instagram

Tags: android

i want custom progress bar like 'instagram' application available in play store here you can see the instagram application 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instagram.android&hl=en
. actually i want circular progress bar and i can set custom progress in progress bar.

i found some solution but that's not worked fro me.

please help some one , thanks in advance

e.g.

[image]

Comment: What was your solution and why did it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go through : https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel this will help you.

Comment: Please don't simply post links as answers, if the site goes down it is useless. Why would it help?

Comment: It's a relevant link to a library-project. If the library goes down, the link goes down, the answer goes down ; okay. But the poster is not gonna post the entire library here. Why would it help? It provides the exact same visual as the OP requested.

Comment: I used this library and it will help you make exactly what you want. @BenjaminPaul, do you think that would be smarter post whole code, with all resources here?

Comment: yes BenjaminPaul...but if a link can help you more clearly..then its fine...Atlast rules are made for everyone's convenience..