# Android - Round ProgressBar starts at wrong place

Tags: android, progress-bar

I'm trying to add a round progress bar to my app which I want to start at the top of the circle and end at the top. However, anything I try with the angles etc doesn't change the appearance. I'm fairly new to Android so go easy on me. Here is my code:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="30" />
```

**circle_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="ring"
android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
android:thickness="6dp"
android:useLevel="false">

<solid android:color="#CCC" />

</shape>
```

**circular_progress_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="270"
android:toDegrees="270" >
<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="6dp">
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#38C0F4"
        android:startColor="#38C0F4"
        android:centerColor="#56ccb7"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
</rotate>
</clip>
```

Here is a screenshot of what is looks like at 30% progress:
[image: 30% progress]

Comment: i think you need to refer this link it will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313998/progress-bar-custom-design-like-instagram/27314020#27314020 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your circular_progress_bar.xml

1. Get rid of the clip tags
2. Add [android:useLevel="true"] to the shape properties. (This is new for Android 5(21))

   ```
   <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fromDegrees="270"
   android:toDegrees="270" >
   <shape
       android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
       android:shape="ring"
       android:thickness="6dp"
       android:useLevel="true">
       <gradient
           android:angle="0"
           android:endColor="#38C0F4"
           android:startColor="#38C0F4"
           android:centerColor="#56ccb7"
           android:type="sweep"
           android:useLevel="false" />
   </shape>
   </rotate>
   ```